# H.264 ( over RTP ) - Videoframes / Reference Frames?

Tags: video, h.264, rtp, mpeg-4

I have a little understanding problem with the terminology at H.264.

When I receive a Stream over RTP I usually get some split up packages which I need to reassemble. It would be something like this:

```
[RTP Frame 0 / has Start Bit]
[RTP Frame 1]
[RTP Frame 2]
[RTP Frame n / has Stop Bit]
[RTP Frame n+1 / has Start Bit]
[....]
```

In this example I would need to put Frame 0 until Frame n together ( then add preceding NAL Bits etc. ).

So in the [RFC3984](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3984.txt) such a "unit" is referred to as a "Video Frame"

Now my question is; **Is such a Video Frame the same as a Reference Frame?**

Answer (score 1):

"Video Frame" refers to a frame of any type with a reference frame being one possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Fragmentation units (as you are describing with the start and stop bits) are used to split a single NAL unit into multiple fragments, typically based on the MTU of the network. A NAL unit is *not* necessarily a video frame. You can read up on the various NAL unit types in the [H.264 standard](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264).

To quote from the updated [RFC 6184](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184#section-5.8):

> This payload type allows fragmenting a NAL unit into several RTP
> packets.